# Dual Boot - NVME SDD and HDD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, nvme

I have a 256 GB NVME SSD (Windows installed from factory) and a 1 TB HDD (in which I have installed Ubuntu). 
The boot sector for windows is in the SSD and the boot sector for Ubuntu is in the HDD. Even though I have updated grub and tried multiple fixes I cannot manage to boot Windows. 
The only boot option for Windows in Grub is Windows Boot Manager which launches Windows in recovery mode.

```
(base) twisted@twisted:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hVvGCqwN7y/ -> Pastebin with boot repair log.

I am stuck. Please help! Thank you in advance

Edit: Solved!
`Switching back from AHCI to RST solved the boot issues`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the answer. For anyone that might have this issue.

When I've installed Ubuntu, RST is not supported so I had to switch to AHCI.
`Windows won't boot in AHCI, it would just load the recovery mode.
After going back in the UEFI and switch it back to RST premium, both Windows and Ubuntu boot normally.`